# Ошибка при установке Django на Ubuntu: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

Tags: python, ubuntu, django

Не могу установить Django на Ubuntu, помогите, пожалуйста.

```
(studentsdb) fantbook@FantBook:/data/work/virtualenvs/studentsdb$ pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-E7rbg6/django/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-E7rbg6/django/
```

Comment: Версия питона слишком старая?

Comment: @andreymal 2.7.12

Comment: А нужно хотя бы 3.5

Comment: Удалите ваше виртуальное окружение (не забыв `deactivate`) и пересоздайте его командой `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 /data/work/virtualenvs/studentsdb` (или другой подобной, но `--python` не забудьте)

Comment: @andreymal не помогло:(

Comment: Може стоит поставить через пакетный менеджер? Ну типа `sudo apt install python3-django`?

Answer (score 2):

в стандартную библиотект functools 'lru_cache'был добавлен в 3 версии питона.
поэтому думаю, что в вашем виртальном окружении используется 2-я версия.

убедитесь что у вас на ОС убунте есть 3 версия.`python3`

офтоп, но это будет полезно.

Каждый запуск проекта требует активации виртуального окружения. Например для того, чтобы запустить проект А, вам нужно зайти в директорию виртуального окружения и запустить команду `source my_env/bin/activate` и это не всегда приятно, поэтому к нам на помощь приходит `virtualenvwrapper`.

просто запустив команду `workon my_env` вы активируете вирт. окружение с названием my_env. прочитайте [документацию](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
и так

1. установить pip3: `sudo apt-get install python-pip3`
2. установка: `sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`
3. `export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs`
4. `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3`
5. `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`
6. `mkvirtualenv  myenv`

в результате слева будет название вашего виртуального окружения:
(myenv) login@laptop_name: ~$